# Cronjob in 000webhost.com don't work

Tags: php, cron

I want this cronjob to run every 5 minutes, but it's working only every hour.

In the `cronjob.php` file I got this:

```
<?php

file_get_contents('http://cars-news.tk/index2.php');
```

In this file `index2.php` is my code which I want to run every 5 minutes.

In 000webhost I have this

```
» Time                    » Command to run           
5 * * * *   php -f /home/a7707017/public_html/cronjob.php
```

What is wrong with my cronjob?

Comment: i just checked your website.... it is running very slow in my opinion. not related to your problem but just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a slash -

```
*/5 * * * *   php -f /home/a7707017/public_html/cronjob.php
```